# How to catch an exception in python and get a reference to the exception, WITHOUT knowing the type?

Tags: python, exception, jython

I'm wondering how I can catch **any** raised object (i.e. a type that does not extend `Exception`), and still get a reference to it.

I came across the desire to do this when using Jython.   When calling a Java method, if that method raises an exception, it will not extend Python's `Exception` class, so a block like this will not catch it:

```
try:
    # some call to a java lib that raises an exception here
except Exception, e:
    # will never be entered
```

I can do this, but then I have no access to the exception object that was raised.

```
try:
    # some call to a java lib that raises an exception here
except:
    # will enter here, but there's no reference to the exception that was raised
```

I can solve this by importing the Java exception type and catching it explicitly, but this makes it difficult/impossible to write generic exception handling wrappers/decorators.

Is there a way to catch some arbitrary exception and still get a reference to it in the `except` block?

**I should note** that I'm hoping for the exception handling decorator I am making to be usable with Python projects, not just with Jython projects.  I'd like to avoid importing `java.lang.Exception` because that just makes it Jython-only.  For example, I figure I can do something like this (but I haven't tried it), but I'd like to avoid it if I can.

```
try:
    # some function that may be running jython and may raise a java exception
except (Exception, java.lang.Exception), e:
    # I imagine this would work, but it makes the code jython-only
```

Comment: Do these exceptions at least derive from BaseException?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can reference exceptions using the [`sys`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) module. [`sys.exc_info`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) is a tuple of the type, the instance and the traceback.

```
import sys

try:
    # some call to a java lib that raises an exception here
except:
    instance = sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, I have found that if you add this import to your Jython script:

```
from java.lang import Exception
```

and just use the conventional Python Exception handler:

```
except Exception, e:
```

it will catch *both* Python exceptions *and* Java exceptions

Answer (score 5):

Just for anyone interested... I spent a bit of time testing stuff because I wanted to find out how to get a proper stack trace whether a Python Exception (BaseException in fact, which is the base class) or a java.lang.Throwable (java base class for Exception, Error, etc.) is thrown... this code illustrates how to catch all line number refs correctly.

```
import sys
import traceback
import java

print "hello world"

def custom_hook( type, exc, tb ):
  if isinstance( sys.exc_info()[ 1 ], java.lang.Throwable ):
    sys.stderr.write( "AS JAVA:\n" )
    sys.exc_info()[ 1 ].printStackTrace() # java part
  else:
    sys.stderr.write( "NO JAVA TRACE:\n" )
  sys.stderr.write( "AS PYTHON:\n" )
  traceback.print_exc()

# useful for custom exception handling!
sys.excepthook = custom_hook  

def handle_exc():
# generate either a java.lang.Throwable (uncomment the next line and comment out "a = 16 / 0"
#  java.lang.String( None )
# OR... a python-style BaseException:
  a = 16 / 0 

class Task( java.lang.Runnable ):
  def run( self ):
    # NB the problem with all this stuff is that the Java stack trace shows
    # a java.lang.Throwable occurring at the last line of this code block...
#    print "lots of stuff first"
#    print "lots 2"
#    handle_exc()
#    print "lots 3"
#    print "lots of stuff after"

    try:
      print "lots of stuff first"
      print "lots 2"
      handle_exc()
      print "lots 3"
      print "lots of stuff after"
    # NB do not catch both (Python) BaseException and java.lang.Throwable...   
#    except ( BaseException, java.lang.Throwable ), e:
    # the above means that the line no. in handle_exc is not shown when a BaseException  
    # is thrown...
    except java.lang.Throwable, t:
      tb = sys.exc_info()[ 2 ] 
      sys.stderr.write( "java.lang.Throwable thrown at: %s\n" % tb.tb_lineno )
      raise t

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait( Task() )
```

After this one might think of writing a decorator to precede def run( self ) and similar methods so that you don't have to write out this catch-the-Throwable try-except block each time... specifically:

```
def throw_trap( function ):
  def wrapper(*args, **kvargs):
    try:
      return function( *args, **kvargs )
    except  java.lang.Throwable, t:
      tb = sys.exc_info()[ 2 ]
      while( tb ): 
        sys.stderr.write( "thrown at: %s\n" % tb.tb_lineno )
        tb = tb.tb_next
      raise t
  return wrapper



def handle_exc():
  java.lang.String( None )
#  a = 16 / 0 


class Task( java.lang.Runnable ):
  @throw_trap
  def run( self ):
    print "lots of stuff first"
    print "lots 2"
    handle_exc()
    print "lots 3"
    print "lots of stuff after"

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait( Task() )
```